# Como posso verificar se uma variável está no formato date?

Tags: php

Bom, pretendo verificar se uma variável $x está no formato de data (yy-mm-dd), como poderei fazer isso com PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com uma expressão regular dessa forma(link da função [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)):

$string = "07-12-30";

```
// para anos com 4 digitos preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}$/', $string)
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}$/', $string)) {
  echo "FOI";
}else{
  echo 'Não foi';
}
```

Você pode completar sua validação vendo se data é valida dessa forma (tirada [daqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.checkdate.php)):

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}


var_dump(validateDate("07-12-30","y-m-d"));
var_dump(validateDate("2007-12-30","Y-m-d")); //quatro digitos
```

Comment: Consegue-me explicar melhor essa function? Normalmente o formato ano  , tem 4 digitos.

Comment: Ele vai validar o formato... se o ano tem 4 digitos você muda o preg_match preg_match('/^d{4}-d{1,2}-d{1,2}$/', $string)

Comment: Eu alterei para d{4} e coloquei a seguinte data: 2017-12-30, e alterei o d para 4, e deu "Não Foi".

Comment: A segunda function, já funciona! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada na primeira

Comment: Pronto! Acabei de arrumar a primeira solução! Você pode usá-las em conjunto!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode executar uma função unica também. Como abaixo:

```
function checkData($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
 if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}[-][0-9]{1,2}$/', $date)) {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
 }
 else{
   return false;
 }
}
$date = "08-11-29";
var_dump(checkDate($date,"y-m-d"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Quer trabalhar com datas no PHP? Esqueça *regex* ou `explode` de *strings* ou reinventar a roda para fazer cálculos com datas... Gaste um tempinho estudando o [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) e verá que tudo além dele é perda de tempo!

Entenda como funciona os [formatos de data no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php), reflita sobre qual o formato de data você irá receber e use a função [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) para validar a sua data:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', '13-02-12'); // $date será válido

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', '2013-02-12'); // $date será false
```